# Change pythonpath in Vim

Tags: vim, python, python3

I'm using [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) for [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) coding. The problem is, that I'm writing in Python 3 and Vim settings contain only Python 2.7 paths. That does not allow me to use plugins (like python-mode) for autocomletion and running scripts. Do I have to recompile Vim with Python 3 support (currently `vim --version` shows "-python3") or can I simply add `/usr/lib/python3` to Vim's $pythonpath?

My OS is [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use Python 3, you need to have support for the Python 3 interpreter built into Vim, as such plugins will use the `:python3` command to run that code. Also, I don't think that the Python 2 interpreter would be able to correctly run Python 3 code from that version's library path.

So yes, you need to install / compile a Vim version with `+python3`.